# How to read source code of a dialog box in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-9, developer-tools, browser-automation

I am automating a web application using ruby and selenium-webdriver which contains multiple fields in dialog boxes. And these dialog boxes contains lot of nested iframes. I am unable to get the element properties using the Developer Tool as everything is disabled for a dialog box. For the time being i am using page_source function of selenium webdriver to read the source but it is of little use in case of nested frames.

Please tell me a good way to identify elements in a dialog box in Internet Explorer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow below steps to fix this issue

1. Open Internet Explorer
2. Click the "Tools" gear (Alt+X)
3. Select "Internet options"
4. Select the "Security" tab
5. Click the "Custom level..." button
   6 .Disable the "Allow websites to open windows without address or status bars" option
6. Hit OK
7. Hit OK

Now find a modal window and press F12

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kurlak/archive/2012/08/27/opening-the-internet-explorer-developer-tools-dialog-on-modal-windows.aspx